# Rails Collection Select in Form not Saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

For whatever reason, this isn't saving. It will give me a success and redirect to the page it is supposed to but the page_id on the group item is nil.

```
<%= simple_form_for group do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :page_id, 
        collection: @pages,
        selected: group.page,
        label: false
        %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Assign Page" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def update
  group = Group.find(params[:id])
  group.update_attributes(group_params)
  redirect_to groups_path, notice: "Did it"
end
```

And params (I have tried every variation on this I could). An odd bit here, the form seems to be creating a nested param.

```
def group_params
  params.require(:group).permit(:name, :page, :group => [:page_id])
end
```

The returned request params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch",
"authenticity_token"=>"Cccccii383838=",
"group"=>{"page_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Assign Page",
"action"=>"update", "controller"=>"groups", "id"=>"3"}
```

A group has_one page. A page has_one group. The associated ids are on each of the models.

Any thoughts? I'm banging my head against the wall for something that is probably a silly problem.

Comment: group  `belongs_to page` should be your association

Comment: I guess you are permitting `page_id` in **group_params**. Can you try with **update_attributes!** and check for validation errors

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ? I think the problem is with  `group_params` method

```
def group_params
  params.require(:group).permit(:page_id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= simple_form_for @group do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :page_id, 
        collection: @pages,
        selected: group.page,
        label: false
        %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Assign Page" %>
<% end %>
```

groups_controller.rb

```
def update
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  @group.update_attributes(group_params)
  redirect_to groups_path, notice: "Did it"
end

def group_params
  params.require(:group).permit(:name, :page_id)
end
```

and your association should be page has_one group and group belongs_to page

Answer (score 0):

Replace the strong parameters in controller

```
def group_params
  params.require(:group).permit(:name, :page, :page_id)
end
```